# Deleting Folders On Server

Tags: php

I accidentally have created some folders on server with a function and instead of using "/" I used this "\". Now the folders are like this : "folder\MartonMihaiBusinessCard" .

I cannot delete them anymore. What can I do about this ?

Comment: Can't you just go into your filemanager, select the directories in question, and click "delete"?  Whap happens if you try?

Comment: @paulsm4 if he's on a shared host, PHP likely isn't running under his user, so he'll have to use PHP.

Comment: Please paste some code here so that the problem be easy to understand,,

Comment: I used mkdir to create the new folder. And no, if I try to delete via FTP it won't work. And I don't have a cPanel, it's GoDaddy Shared Hosting. My only option is either FTP or as I saw PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used PHP to create them, they're likely owned by some funky user like "nobody" or "apache". So, you'll have to use PHP to delete them, too.

This doesn't work out of the box with filenames containing backslashes, as you've found. This is because the backslash is treated as an "escape" character in PHP. Something like "my\new\file" will actually contain a linebreak and a carriage feed.

However, if you escape the backslash-- with another backslash!-- you'll be able to point PHP at the file.

```
rmdir("/path/to/the/folder\\MartonMihaiBusinessCard");
```

(or `unlink()` if it's actually a file, I wasn't clear on that) should do what you seek.

Comment: OK. And where do I put this ? Right before deleting the folder, I mean the command for deleting ?

Comment: You could put this in any PHP file and allow PHP to execute it by going to the page in a web browser. Note that I updated my answer to cover either directories or files as your later comment was a little unclear as to whether you actually created a folder or a file in the end.

Comment: It's a folder. OK. So this simple remove directory should do the trick. I hope so because I kept trying with simple delete via FTP and changing permissions and so on. Thank you :)